# Install Radeon R3 graphics card driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics, nomodeset

I'm beginner in ubuntu user. My system is laptop computer, using AMD Quad-Core processor (1.8GHz 2MB L2 Cache) and AMD Radeon R3 Graphics. The manufacture notice like that, so I don't know more information.

I have some troubles in Ubuntu 18.04, The monitor can't changes brightness and night mode. I want to boot using graphic card, But it shows only black screen, so I'm using nomodeset while booting.

I found some tips that using these commands...

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:trebelnik-stefina/radeon-profile
sudo apt update
sudo apt install radeon-profile
```

...it installed well, but when I run the 'Radeon Profile' program, "no Radeon cards have been found in the system" is shown.

Comment: I do not have a solution but according to your specs it could be a lenovo ideapad 330 with a AMD A4-9125 and the mentioned Radeon R3 GPU. I recently installed mint 19 and this version runs fine. But a GPU (Radeon) is not detected as well. But at least it runs great on this laptop. Although you will need a special wifi driver as mentioned here: https://gist.github.com/debojyoti/228729498628e898497557db57619a28 The touchpad will work with the kernel of mint 19.2

Comment: Thanks for mention it. I tried it, but it works something bad... sometimes freezed ...etc, so... I reinstall ubuntu.